# Can I use "using" in a yield-return-method?

Tags: c#, using, yield-return

I just saw a YouTube video, where the tutor used a yield return method to open a file and read lines from it, that are yield-returned to the caller (the actual code was in a using block around the FileStream).

Then I wondered, is it OK to use "using" or "try-finally" in a yield-return method. Because my understanding is, that the method only runs as long, as values are get from it. With "Any()" for example the method is done, after the first yield return (or yield break of course).

So, if the function never runs to end, when is the finally block executed? Is it safe to use such a construct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`IEnumerator<T>` implements `IDisposable`, and `foreach` loops will dispose the thing they're enumerating over when they're finished (this includes linq methods which use a `foreach` loop, such as `.ToArray()`).

It turns out that the compiler-generated state machine for generator methods implements `Dispose` in a smart way: if the state machine is in a state which is "inside" a `using` block, then calling `Dispose()` on the state machine will dispose the thing protected by the `using` statement.

---

Let's take an example:

```
public IEnumerable<string> M() {
    yield return "1";
    using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        yield return "2";  
        yield return "3";
    }
    yield return "4";
}
```

I'm not going to paste the entire generated state machine, as it's very large. [You can see it on SharpLab here](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgZgpghgLgrgJwgZwLQBMD2MB2EYBimCAtrADTogDUAPgAIAMABPQIwAsA3ALABQTVmwB0ASQDyvAQGZWAJmYBhZgG9+zDa1ntpAHnaMAfMwCyACgCUq9Ztvs2rAOzMARGxdTbdlmYBuUBGYSZGYAXmY8AHdTCBJiAE8AZRgkKBJLCxsvaz5s7PsnVzkPDSy8jQL6ZxdpDzLbAF96zUrqjjrczSa+bqA==).

The core of the state machine is the following switch statement, which tracks our progress past each of the `yield return` statements:

```
switch (<>1__state)
{
    default:
        return false;
    case 0:
        <>1__state = -1;
        <>2__current = "1";
        <>1__state = 1;
        return true;
    case 1:
        <>1__state = -1;
        <ms>5__1 = new MemoryStream();
        <>1__state = -3;
        <>2__current = "2";
        <>1__state = 2;
        return true;
    case 2:
        <>1__state = -3;
        <>2__current = "3";
        <>1__state = 3;
        return true;
    case 3:
        <>1__state = -3;
        <>m__Finally1();
        <ms>5__1 = null;
        <>2__current = "4";
        <>1__state = 4;
        return true;
    case 4:
        <>1__state = -1;
        return false;
}
```

You can see that we create the `MemoryStream` as we enter state 2, and dispose it (by calling `<>m__Finally1()`) as we exit state 3.

Here's the `Dispose` method:

```
void IDisposable.Dispose()
{
    int num = <>1__state;
    if (num == -3 || (uint)(num - 2) <= 1u)
    {
        try
        {
        }
        finally
        {
            <>m__Finally1();
        }
    }
}
```

If we're in states -3, 2, or 3, then we'll call `<>m__Finally1();`. States 2 and 3 are those inside the `using` block.

(State -3 seems to be a guard in case we wrote `yield return Foo()` and `Foo()` threw an exception: in this case we would stay in state -3 and would be unable to iterate any further. However we are still allowed to dispose the `MemoryStream` in this case).

Just for completeness, `<>m__Finally1` is defined as:

```
private void <>m__Finally1()
{
    <>1__state = -1;
    if (<ms>5__1 != null)
    {
        ((IDisposable)<ms>5__1).Dispose();
    }
}
```

---

You can find the specification for this in the [C# Language Specification](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=7029), section 10.14.4.3:

> - If the state of the enumerator object is suspended, invoking Dispose:
>
>   - Changes the state to running.
>   - Executes any finally blocks as if the last executed yield return statement were a yield break statement. If this causes an exception to be thrown and propagated out of the iterator body, the state of the enumerator object is set to after and the exception is propagated to the caller of the Dispose method.
>   - Changes the state to after.

Answer (score 2):

I just wrote some test code, and it seems that the destructor is called everytime at an appropriate point.

```cs
struct Test : IDisposable
{
    public void Dispose() => Console.WriteLine("Destructor called");
}

static IEnumerable<int> InfiniteInts()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Constructor Called");
    using(var test = new Test()) {
        int i = 0;
        while(true)
            yield return ++i;
    }
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var seq = InfiniteInts();
    Console.WriteLine("Call Any()");
    bool b = seq.Any();
    Console.WriteLine("Call Take().ToArray()");
    int[] someInts = seq.Take(20).ToArray();

    Console.WriteLine("foreach loop");
    foreach(int i in seq)
    {
        if(i > 20) break;
    }

    Console.WriteLine("do it manually: while loop");
    var enumerator = seq.GetEnumerator();
    while(enumerator.MoveNext())
    {
         int i = enumerator.Current;
         if(i > 20) break;
    }
    Console.WriteLine("No destructor call has happened!");

    enumerator.Dispose();
    Console.WriteLine("Now destructor has beend called");

    Console.WriteLine("End of Block");
}
```

After I called `seq.Any()`, I already got the `"Destuctor called"` message before the `"Call Take().ToArray()"` message.

The same was for the `seq.Take(20).ToArray()` statement. The destructor was called.

I dug a little deeper. It seems like the `IEnumerator<int>` that is created is itself an `IDisposable`. All Linq methods probably call this Dispose method, when they are done.

Only, if I use the enumerator manually, I have to call Dispose on it. I think, this is the reason this works.