# C# SqlClient | Connection Pooling | Error When Opening Second Connection

Tags: c#, sqlclient

I'm trying to figure out how to setup my database access correctly while using the SqlClient hitting a Microsoft SQL Server. For the most part it is working, but there's a particular scenario that is giving me trouble. Namely: attempting to simultaneously use two connections in the same thread; one with an open data reader and the other performing a delete operation.

The following code demonstrates my conundrum:

```
public class Database { 
   ...
   internal SqlConnection CreateConnection() => new SqlConnection(connectionString);
   ...
}
```

```
public IEnumerable<Model> GetModel() {
   var cmd = new SqlCommand() { ... };
   using(var conn = db.CreateConnection()) {
      conn.Open();
      cmd.Connection = conn;
      using(var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader()) {
         while(reader.Read()) {
            var m = new Model();
            // deserialization logic
            yield return m;
         }
      }
   }
}

public void Delete(int id) {
   var cmd = new SqlCommand() { ... }
   using(var conn = db.CreateConnection()) {
      conn.Open(); // throwing the error here
      cmd.Connection = conn;
      cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
   }
}
```

Application Code:

```
using(var scope = new TransactionScope()) {
   var models = GetModels();
   foreach(var m in models) {
      Delete(m.Id); // throws an exception
   }
   scope.Complete();
}
```

For whatever reason, an exception is thrown by the above code while trying to execute the Delete operation:

> quote
> System.Transactions.TransactionAbortedException: The transaction has aborted. ---> System.Transactions.TransactionPromotionException: Failure while attempting to promote transaction. ---> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command which must be closed first. ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The wait operation timed out
> quote

Now, I have confirmed that if I either set `MultipleActiveResultSets=true` or `Pooling=false` on the ConnectionString, that then the above application code will work without error. However, it doesn't seem like I should need to set either of those. If I open two connections simultaneously, should they not be separate connections? Why then am I getting an error from the Delete connection saying that there's an open DataReader?

Please help <3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By far the easiest fix here is to simply load all the models outside the transaction before you go deleting any.  Eg

```
var models = GetModels().ToList();
using(var scope = new TransactionScope()) {
 
   foreach(var m in models) {
      Delete(m.Id); // throws an exception
   }
   scope.Complete();
}
```

Even fetching the models inside the transaction shold work

```
using(var scope = new TransactionScope()) {
   var models = GetModels().ToList(); 
   foreach(var m in models) {
      Delete(m.Id); // throws an exception
   }
   scope.Complete();
}
```

so long as you don't leave the connection open during the iteration.  If you allow the connection in GetModels() to close, it will be returned to the connection pool, and be available for use for subsequent methods that are enlisted in the same transaction.

In the current code the connection in GetModels() is kept open during the `foreach` loop and `Delete(id)` has to open a second connection and try to create a distributed transaction, which is failing.

Without MultipleActiveResultsets, the GetModels connection can't be promoted to a distributed transaction in the middle of returning query results.  Setting pooling=false will not make this error go away.

Here's a simplified repro to play with:

```
using Microsoft.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Transactions;

namespace SqlClientTest
{

    class Program
    {

        
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            Setup();

            var topt = new TransactionOptions();
            topt.IsolationLevel = System.Transactions.IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted;
            using (new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Required,  topt ))
            {
                foreach (var id in GetIds())
                {
                    Delete(id);
                }

            }

        }

        static string constr = @"server=.;database=tempdb;Integrated Security=true;TrustServerCertificate=true;";


        public static void Setup()
        {
            using (var con = new SqlConnection(constr))
            {
                con.Open();
                var cmd = con.CreateCommand();
                cmd.CommandText = "drop table if exists ids; select object_id id into ids from sys.objects";
                
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }

        public static IEnumerable<int> GetIds()
        {
            using (var con = new SqlConnection(constr))
            {
                con.Open();
                var cmd = con.CreateCommand();
                cmd.CommandText = "select object_id id from sys.objects";
                using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        yield return reader.GetInt32(0);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        public static void Delete(int id)
        {
            using (var con = new SqlConnection(constr))
            {
                con.Open();
                var cmd = con.CreateCommand();
                cmd.CommandText = "insert into ids(id) values (@id)";
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@id", id));

                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }

    }

}
```

And here's what Profiler shows when run:

[image]

Comment: Why does it require `.ToList()`? I should be able to stream the model instances one at a time vs pulling them all down

Comment: Streaming them prevents the two methods from sharing the same connection through the connection pool.  You could explicitly share a MARS connection though.

Comment: Yes - they should be two distinct connections. I call CreateConnection twice to that end, so not sure why that doesn't work

Comment: Because you’ve asked them to be enlisted in the same transaction, but you’re trying to create a distributed transaction when one session is in the middle of running a query.

Comment: Ah, so the fact that they are within the same transaction is what is causing the SqlClient to incorrectly use the same connection which is already in use? They need to be within the same transaction - is there a way to force the SqlClient to properly use a separate connection here? Perhaps I should setup a parameter to CreateConnection that determines if the new connection should be pooled or not... Or is MARs a more efficient solution in such a scenario? Wish I could find some documentation on this front

Comment: You're misunderstanding what's going on here.  Read the docs on how [Connection Pooling interacts with TransactionScope](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql-server-connection-pooling#transaction-support) and how [light-weight promotable transactions work](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/clr-integration-data-access-transactions/transaction-promotion?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: If I turn off pooling, such that it is creating a new connection every time, then it works. Since they are distinct connections within the same transaction, then isn't it getting promoted to a Distributed Transaction? And if so, then that shouldn't be the cause of why I'm seeing an error in this scenario with a pooled connection. In fact, the error message indicates not that there is an issue with promoting the transaction, but rather that upon creating the second SqlConnection the pool has returned an underlying db connection that is already in use by the DataReader.

Comment: No.  Promotion is when two _different_ SqlConnections are enlisted in the same System.Transactions.Transaction.  If you had one SqlConnection, all the SqlCommands would automatically share a transaction.  The Connection Pool can't return the _same_ SqlConnection in `Delete()` since the SqlConnection in `GetModels()` is still open.

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm saying. If I turn pooling off, then the GetModels() operation will execute over connection A and the Delete operation will execute over connection B, and both are still in a common (distributed) transaction. This will complete successfully.

What I'm missing from your explanation is why, when pooling is enabled, opening connection B for the Delete operation is throwing an error that that connection already has an open DataReader on it if in fact the SqlClient returned a distinct connection? Clearly the SqlClient is returning resources that are already in use.

Comment: See updated answer.

Comment: Your last comment in your updated answer is incorrect. I have confirmed through testing that turning pooling off will make this code succeed as expected - without turning on MARs.

Comment: See repro in updated answer, transaction enlistment and promotion happen even without pooling, and there are definitely two seperate connections to SQL Server.

Comment: Exactly my point, which seems to just confirm that the SqlClient pooling isn't functioning properly

Comment: It works exactly as documented.

Comment: The doc says that it should return a connection that isn't actively being used

Comment: But it _is_ actively being used.  Put a breakpoint at the end of the `using` block in `GetModel()`.  You'll see that the `using` block hasn't finished and so the SqlConnection has not been Disposed and returned to the connection pool.

Comment: Again, exactly my point. Since the GetModel() connection is actively being used, then the Delete connection should be distinct from the first - and thus there should be no conflict with the open DataReader on the GetModel() connection

Comment: But you've required the first SqlConnection and the second SqlConnection to be enlisted in the same Transaction.  The enlistment and promotion of the first SqlConnection is what's failing.

Comment: It's not though. I know this because if I turn pooling off then it works (and thus promotion is working). Also, the error is very explicit about why it's failing: because of the open DataReader on the previously opened connection. So the SqlClient is attempting to re-use an active connection

Comment: That's not what's happening.  Run the repro in the answer.

Comment: Hmmm - I'm trying out your code. If I add "MultipleActiveResultSets=True;" to the connection string it's still failing for me

Comment: Do you have MSDTC running?  If not the promotion will still fail.

Comment: Using MultipleActiveResultSets works on my database, but not on this test one. I'm missing some important piece of the setup process. I'm going to keep testing using the code you provided and investigate further until I can pinpoint the configuration difference, which in turn will probably make it easier to explain why I'm seeing the behavior I'm seeing. Thank you for all your help!

Answer (score 0):

The main reason here as far as I understand is your yielding iteration.

So the DB connection has not yet called disposed as it's still being used in your iteration (foreach). If for example, you called `.ToList()` at that point it should return all the entries and then dispose of the connection.

See here for a better explanation on how `yield`  works in an iteration: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58449809/3329836

Comment: I'm intentionally wanting the deferred execution to work. I'm ostensibly creating a new connection, so it's unclear why the two connections are conflicting when Pooling is enabled. It's not the yield usage that I don't understand, but why opening a second connection B throws an exception while connection A has an open DataReader???