# Why is ExecuteReader closing?

Tags: c#, sql, database, sqldatareader

I am developing an app in `WPF`. I am trying to fetch email, extract data, save it in DB and work with it in `DataGrid`. To avoid saving duplicates, I have made a method for that. My problem is, that I don't know why my `dataReader` is closed? If I am using it in another .xaml class it works properly, so what is wrong here? I have used `using-statement`, where I thought was the problem, but it seems that it is not.

DataReader method:

```cs
public IEnumerable<Problem> GetAll()
{
    using (SqlConnection conn = DatabaseSingleton.GetInstance())
    {
        //conn.Open();
        using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Problem", conn))
        {
            using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    Problem problem = new Problem
                    {
                        Id = reader.GetInt32(0),
                        NameOfAlert = reader.GetString(1),
                        Value = Enum.Parse<Value>(reader[2].ToString()),
                        Result = Enum.Parse<Result>(reader[3].ToString()),
                        Message_Id = reader.GetString(4)
                    };
                    yield return problem;
                }
            }
        }
        //conn.Close();
    }
}
```

Method for fetching emails:

```cs
public static void MailKitLib(EmailParser emailParser)
{
    bool help = true;
    
    do
    {
        using (var client = new ImapClient())
        {
            using (var cancel = new System.Threading.CancellationTokenSource())
            {
                client.Connect(emailParser.ServerName, emailParser.Port, emailParser.IsSSLuse, cancel.Token);
                client.Authenticate(emailParser.Username, emailParser.Password, cancel.Token);
    
                var inbox = client.Inbox;
                inbox.Open(FolderAccess.ReadOnly, cancel.Token);
    
                //Here I am saving only originals
                for (int i = 0; i < inbox.Count; i++)
                {
                    var message = inbox.GetMessage(i, cancel.Token);
                    GetBodyText = message.TextBody;
                    Problem problem = new Problem(message.MessageId);
                    if (!dAOProblem.GetAll().Any(x => x.Message_Id.Equals(problem.Message_Id)))
                    {
                        dAOProblem.Save(problem);
                        Alert alert = new Alert(message.MessageId, message.Date.DateTime, message.From.ToString(), 1, problem.Id);
                        if (!dAOAlert.GetAll().Any(x => x.Id_MimeMessage.Equals(alert.Id_MimeMessage)))
                        {
                            dAOAlert.Save(alert);
                        }
                    }
                }
                //client.Disconnect(true, cancel.Token);
            }
        }
    } while (help != false);
}
```

UPDATE:
This is exactly what I have tried. But there is also a problem that connection was not closed.

Comment: Where EXACTLY is a data reader closed that you don't think it should be. Please provide specific details.

Comment: `DatabaseSingleton.GetInstance()` Why you use singleton pattern on your SqlConnection?  That does not help at all but can hurt you much, in case of a multi threading app. The "best" what it could do is to reduce performance, because [sql connection pooling](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql-server-connection-pooling) needs to create a new physical connection whener you want to open one. Instead, always create a new instance and use `using (var conn = GetConnection()) ...`. It's important to close the connection to make it reusable for the pool.

Comment: @John in first and second  `if-statement` it throws the exception

Comment: @DiplomacyNotWar Yes I have. How I said I also used using-statement like Tim said before, but without results

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was with `DatabaseSingleton.GetInstance()`, which supported `connection-pooling`

```
 public IEnumerable<Problem> GetAll()
        {
            string connString = "Data Source=;Initial Catalog=;User ID=;Password=";
            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString))
            {
                conn.Open();
                using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Problem", conn))
                {
                    using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        while (reader.Read())
                        {
                            Problem problem = new Problem
                            {
                                Id = reader.GetInt32(0),
                                NameOfAlert = reader.GetString(1),
                                Value = Enum.Parse<Value>(reader[2].ToString()),
                                Result = Enum.Parse<Result>(reader[3].ToString()),
                                Message_Id = reader.GetString(4)

                            };
                            yield return problem;
                        }
                    }
                conn.Close();
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

**First problem**: Get rid of your database singleton. Connection pooling will take care of it. There is no performance gain in you reusing conenctions, let the system handle it.

<s>**Second problem**: `yield` and `using` aren't good friends, because `using` might dispose of the instance before yielding is done. You might be able to solve it by dropping the `using` on the connection and make the reader close the connection when it's done by `CommandBehavior.CloseConnection`. Otherwise look at the solutions here: [yield return statement inside a using() { } block Disposes before executing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1539114/yield-return-statement-inside-a-using-block-disposes-before-executing)</s>

Problem 2 was a misunderstanding of mine. Please see @CharlieFace's comment.

```cs
public IEnumerable<Problem> GetAll()
{
    var conn = new SqlConnection(*connectionString*);
    conn.Open();
    using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Problem", conn))
    {
        using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection))
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                Problem problem = new Problem
                {
                    Id = reader.GetInt32(0),
                    NameOfAlert = reader.GetString(1),
                    Value = Enum.Parse<Value>(reader[2].ToString()),
                    Result = Enum.Parse<Result>(reader[3].ToString()),
                    Message_Id = reader.GetString(4)
                };
                yield return problem;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, thanks for your answer. You was faster than me with posting right answer. But finding that `yield return` and `using` is not good idea is great info. for me. Thanks.

Comment: "`yield` and `using` aren't good friends, because `using` might dispose of the instance before yielding is done." that's not true. It's sorted out by the compiler lifting the implicit `finally`  of the `using` into a `Dispose()` function on the iterator. The issue in the link you posted does not have a `yield return` in the outer function and the solution was to add one. See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/58449809/14868997

Comment: @Charlieface: Sorry for my misunderstanding. I'll edit the answer.